# .htaccess 301 Redirect with spaces and quotes - still not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having a spot of bother with a 301 Redirect via .htaccess, the whole website has just redevloped in WordPress from an "old skool" Perl system from like 10 years ago.

So now we need to redirect the masses of old pages to the new more friendlier and concise ones.

So I have this as my .htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# 301's from OLD site

Redirect 301 "/cgi-bin/utile_cat.pl?cat=1.AIR / GAS COMPRESSORS" "http://www.utileengineering.co.uk/products/air-gas-compressors/"

# END 301's
```

For some reason going to: DOMAIN.CO.UK/cgi-bin/utile_cat.pl?cat=1.AIR / GAS COMPRESSORS will not redirect to the new URL. In firefox it pushes the perl file download which doesn't exist and in other browsers I get the WP 404 page?

I have tralled through may blog posts, forum posts, stackoverflow posts and they all say the same thing... my issue is completely different by the looks of it.

Does anyone have any idea? The hosting is Fasthosts.

The URL is there inside the code snippet above if you need to have a look to see what is going on.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my suggestions is always to use homogeneous tools. I.e. if you use `RewriteRule` keep using `RewriteRule` and don't mix with `Redirect`. This is harder to read for someone else. Stay **homogeneous**.

You want to redirect? Do like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    # 301's from OLD site
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=1.AIR%20/%20GAS%20COMPRESSORS
    RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/utile_cat\.pl$ /products/air-gas-compressors/? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Ain't that much nicer, shorter & maintainable?

### And now two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

May I ask you to add the rewritelog in your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer Olivier, unfortunately this will not work either and I am still getting the same result! I am truly baffled.

P.S What do you mean by "May I ask you to add the rewritelog in your question?"

Comment: I've seen your edit also, and that doesnt make any difference either.. have you gone to: http://www.utileengineering.co.uk/cgi-bin/utile_cat.pl?cat=1.AIR%20/%20GAS%20COMPRESSORS

Comment: Here's what I suggest: activate a rewritelog (see my advice), restart the server an then try to open the problematic URL. Then open the rewritelog and put it here (as code source to avoid indent problems)

Comment: Thanks, I get 500 Internal Server Error when adding your code for the rewrite logs. The path to my htaccess is: /home/fhlinux159/u/utileengineering.co.uk/user/htdocs/.htaccess

Comment: I get these errors: [Thu Dec 15 16:10:43 2011] [alert] [client 82.71.191.213] /home/fhlinux159/u/utileengineering.co.uk/user/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteLog not allowed here

AND:

[Thu Dec 15 15:38:12 2011] [error] [client 90.152.2.234] mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=1.AIR%20/%20GAS%20COMPRESSORS
   RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/utile_cat\.pl$ /products/air-gas-compressors/? [R=301,L] needed a question mark on the end

Comment: Okay that's perfect, I edit my question according to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think that your URL must be encoded in order to function properly (note the %20 instead of spaces) :

```
Redirect 301 "/cgi-bin/utile_cat.pl?cat=1.AIR%20/%20GAS%20COMPRESSORS" "http://www.utileengineering.co.uk/products/air-gas-compressors/"
```

The order of the statements is also important. Perhaps, you should move the 301 redirect to the top in order to be processed before WordPress rewriting rules.

Comment: Thanks Cedric, I have tried this and moved above the WP rewrite code, I can confirm that this still does not work and gives me the same result as I stated above.